# Php Date Function

Tags: php, date, time

I have tried using php date function() like as follows

```
 $date=date('Y-m-d').' '.date('H:i:s');
 echo $date;
```

the output displayed is `2013-04-03 09:04:02`.. but my system is `02:49 pm`...

What time is being displayed for me? I tried changing the internet timing even then I am getting the same answer ?

Comment: The time here is the server time. If you need local machine time, use JS.

Comment: PHP will show only server's time.

Comment: Check your server time AND timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it is not necessary to use the `date` function twice. This will do the same thing:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Second, you need to set PHP's [`date.timezone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone). This can be done in the [`php.ini`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) file, but it can also be done using the [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) function, like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

The string that you have to put in can be [found in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

It may also be worth noting that you can tell the `date` function to use any time. This is done by passing in a [*nix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) as the second argument. For example:

```
// One week ago from now
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()-604800);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will show server's time only. If possible compare with your server time. If you want to use local machine's time you need to go with **JAVASCRIPT**.

And another suggestion,

You don't have to use individually to display date & time. You can achieve this in a single statement like this.

```
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You will get the same format `2013-04-03 09:04:02`

Answer (score 0):

check for your system timezone and your default timezone in php by opening phpinfo()